# How to parse base path from a given URL?

Tags: powershell

Given a URL like this: `https://xyzt-pbi.co.com/reports/powerbi/Platform%20Status%20Reports/MSAS%20PBI%202019%20v10`

How do i parse the server in powershell, in other words, i want this portion only: `xyzt-pbi.co.com`

Comment: `$uri = 'https://xyzt-pbi.co.com/reports/powerbi/Platform%20Status%20Reports/MSAS%20PBI%202019%20v10'; [regex]::Match($uri, '(?://)(.+?)(?:/)').Groups[1].Value`

Comment: @Daniel short and sweet! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast to `[uri]` ([`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Uri)) and access the resulting instance's `.Host` property:

```
PS> (
      [uri] 'https://xyzt-pbi.co.com/reports/powerbi/Platform%20Status%20Reports/MSAS%20PBI%202019%20v10'
    ).Host

xyzt-pbi.co.com
```